# How to extract gender of a person name through spacy-dbpedia-spotlight in python

Tags: python, spacy, spotlight-dbpedia

I am using spacy-dbpedia-spotlight python package for extracting entities information in my NLP project. But I couldn't find in their documentation how to check the gender of person entities found in given text.

Comment: I found this here: https://debuggr.net/solution/ae90c7c5-9ef4-4ccf-a502-de555d420d98